# Hide geckodriver command window selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I have a windows form application. Running the project which contains selenium (geckodriver) it is opening a `Command Window`. How can I hide it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBec6.png)

Below I attached my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();     
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can hide the command prompt window now in Selenium 2.40.0. this a blog article about this earlier, which you might want to have a look [here](https://yizeng.me/2014/03/05/hide-command-prompt-window-in-selenium-webdriver-net-binding/)

Comment: I have tried something like that, but it didn't work.

Comment: I can't create variables `var` instead of `IWebDriver`

Answer (score -1):

I have adapted the code from [here](https://yizeng.me/2014/03/05/hide-command-prompt-window-in-selenium-webdriver-net-binding/) and it worked.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();     
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ar driverService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(driverService, new FirefoxOptions());
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
        }
}
```